# Erlang supervisor/gen_server exception exit: noproc

Tags: emacs, erlang, behavior, erlang-supervisor, gen-server

I'm going insane right now trying to figure out what the problem to this is.

Basically I just want to set up an easy Supervisor with 1 server and 1 gen_event-behaviour module.

Now the problem is that I can't get it to start anymore, the supervisor that is.

I get this error no matter what I do:
** exception exit: noproc

and when using the text-tracer it shows that it happends in sRPG_supervisor:init/1. And with this you think there's something wrong with the code, but I get exactly the same thing when I run other peoples examples of this(I've downloaded Joe Armstrongs examples and tested the sellaprime_supervisor with the same result).

It used to start fine when I ran it in my virtual Ubuntu installation. Then I set it up so I could code in Windows but I never even tested that the simplest form of this worked, and obviously it don't for some reason.

So if someone has had a similar problem, would be great to find a solution!
I'm using erl6.3 as the Erlang version with OTP 17.

Here's the code that I'm using, just a buildup from the Emacs generated skeleton:
sRPG_supervisor.erl

```
-module(sRPG_supervisor).

-behaviour(supervisor).

%% API
-export([start_link/0, start_link/1, start/0, start_in_shell_for_testing/0]).

%% Supervisor callbacks
-export([init/1]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

%%%===================================================================
%%% API functions
%%%===================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc
%% Starts the supervisor
%%
%% @spec start_link() -> {ok, Pid} | ignore | {error, Error}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, []).

start() ->
    spawn(fun() ->
          supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, _Arg = [])
      end).

start_in_shell_for_testing() ->
    {ok, Pid} = supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, _Arg = []),
    unlink(Pid).

start_link(Args) ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, Args).


%%%===================================================================
%%% Supervisor callbacks
%%%===================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Whenever a supervisor is started using supervisor:start_link/[2,3],
%% this function is called by the new process to find out about
%% restart strategy, maximum restart frequency and child
%% specifications.
%%
%% @spec init(Args) -> {ok, {SupFlags, [ChildSpec]}} |
%%                     ignore |
%%                     {error, Reason}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
init([]) ->
    %% Install sRPG event/error handler
    gen_event:swap_handler(alarm_handler, {alarm_handler, swap}, {sRPG_event_handler, xyz}),



    RestartStrategy = one_for_one,
    MaxRestarts = 1000,
    MaxSecondsBetweenRestarts = 3600,

    SupFlags = {RestartStrategy, MaxRestarts, MaxSecondsBetweenRestarts},

    Restart = permanent,
    Shutdown = 2000,
    Type = worker,

    AChild = {sRPG_server, {sRPG_server, start_link, []},
          Restart, Shutdown, Type, [sRPG_server]},

    {ok, {SupFlags, [AChild]}}.
```

sRPG_server.erl

```
-module(sRPG_server).

-behaviour(gen_server).

%% API
-export([start_link/0, testServer/0]).

%% gen_server callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2,
     terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-record(state, {}).

%%%===================================================================
%%% API
%%%===================================================================

testServer() ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {test, test}).


%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc
%% Starts the server
%%
%% @spec start_link() -> {ok, Pid} | ignore | {error, Error}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?SERVER}, ?MODULE, [], []).

%%%===================================================================
%%% gen_server callbacks
%%%===================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Initializes the server
%%
%% @spec init(Args) -> {ok, State} |
%%                     {ok, State, Timeout} |
%%                     ignore |
%%                     {stop, Reason}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
init([]) ->
    %% Note we must set trap_exit = true if we want
    %% terminate/2 to be called when the application is stopped
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    %MainGamePid = gameSystem:start(),

    io:format("~p starting~n", [?MODULE]),
    {ok, #state{}}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Handling call messages
%%
%% @spec handle_call(Request, From, State) ->
%%                                   {reply, Reply, State} |
%%                                   {reply, Reply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                   {noreply, State} |
%%                                   {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                   {stop, Reason, Reply, State} |
%%                                   {stop, Reason, State}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_call({test, test}, _From, State) ->
    io:format("TEST TEST TEST ~n"),
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State};
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {reply, Reply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Handling cast messages
%%
%% @spec handle_cast(Msg, State) -> {noreply, State} |
%%                                  {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                  {stop, Reason, State}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_cast(_Msg, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Handling all non call/cast messages
%%
%% @spec handle_info(Info, State) -> {noreply, State} |
%%                                   {noreply, State, Timeout} |
%%                                   {stop, Reason, State}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% This function is called by a gen_server when it is about to
%% terminate. It should be the opposite of Module:init/1 and do any
%% necessary cleaning up. When it returns, the gen_server terminates
%% with Reason. The return value is ignored.
%%
%% @spec terminate(Reason, State) -> void()
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Convert process state when code is changed
%%
%% @spec code_change(OldVsn, State, Extra) -> {ok, NewState}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================
```

sRPG_event_handler.erl

```
-module(sRPG_event_handler).

-behaviour(gen_event).

%% API
-export([start_link/0, add_handler/0]).

%% gen_event callbacks
-export([init/1, handle_event/2, handle_call/2, 
     handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

-define(SERVER, ?MODULE).

-record(state, {}).

%%%===================================================================
%%% gen_event callbacks
%%%===================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc
%% Creates an event manager
%%
%% @spec start_link() -> {ok, Pid} | {error, Error}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
start_link() ->
    gen_event:start_link({local, ?SERVER}).

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @doc
%% Adds an event handler
%%
%% @spec add_handler() -> ok | {'EXIT', Reason} | term()
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
add_handler() ->
    gen_event:add_handler(?SERVER, ?MODULE, []).

%%%===================================================================
%%% gen_event callbacks
%%%===================================================================

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Whenever a new event handler is added to an event manager,
%% this function is called to initialize the event handler.
%%
%% @spec init(Args) -> {ok, State}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
init([]) ->
    io:format("*** sRPG Event Handler init ***~n"),
    {ok, #state{}};
init(Args) ->
    io:format("*** sRPG Event Handler init: ~p~n", [Args]),
    {ok, #state{}}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Whenever an event manager receives an event sent using
%% gen_event:notify/2 or gen_event:sync_notify/2, this function is
%% called for each installed event handler to handle the event.
%%
%% @spec handle_event(Event, State) ->
%%                          {ok, State} |
%%                          {swap_handler, Args1, State1, Mod2, Args2} |
%%                          remove_handler
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_event({set_alarm, testAlarm}, State) ->
    error_logger:error_msg("*** BEEP BOOP TEST ALARM ***~n"),
    {ok, State};
handle_event({clear_alarm, testAlarm}, State) ->
    error_logger:error_msg("*** Brrrrppp... Test Alarm Over ***~n"),
    {ok, State};
handle_event(_Event, State) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Whenever an event manager receives a request sent using
%% gen_event:call/3,4, this function is called for the specified
%% event handler to handle the request.
%%
%% @spec handle_call(Request, State) ->
%%                   {ok, Reply, State} |
%%                   {swap_handler, Reply, Args1, State1, Mod2, Args2} |
%%                   {remove_handler, Reply}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_call(_Request, State) ->
    Reply = ok,
    {ok, Reply, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% This function is called for each installed event handler when
%% an event manager receives any other message than an event or a
%% synchronous request (or a system message).
%%
%% @spec handle_info(Info, State) ->
%%                         {ok, State} |
%%                         {swap_handler, Args1, State1, Mod2, Args2} |
%%                         remove_handler
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Whenever an event handler is deleted from an event manager, this
%% function is called. It should be the opposite of Module:init/1 and
%% do any necessary cleaning up.
%%
%% @spec terminate(Reason, State) -> void()
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
%% @private
%% @doc
%% Convert process state when code is changed
%%
%% @spec code_change(OldVsn, State, Extra) -> {ok, NewState}
%% @end
%%--------------------------------------------------------------------
code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%%%===================================================================
%%% Internal functions
%%%===================================================================
```

and here's examples of what happens:

```
Eshell V6.3  (abort with ^G)
1> sRPG_supervisor:start_link().
** exception exit: noproc
2> sRPG_supervisor:start_in_shell_for_testing().
** exception exit: noproc
3> ServPid = sRPG_server:start_link().
sRPG_server starting
{ok,<0.39.0>}
4> gen_server:call(sRPG_server, {test, test}).
TEST TEST TEST 
ok
```

As you can see the server works when called without a supervisor.

I've looked hard at the similar problems others have had, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the `sasl` application is running, no `alarm_handler` will be running either, and the `noproc` exception occurs in your supervisor `init` as a result. Try this:

```
1> application:start(sasl).
ok
2> sRPG_supervisor:start_in_shell_for_testing().
*** sRPG Event Handler init: {xyz,{alarm_handler,[]}}
sRPG_server starting

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 12-Aug-2015::17:00:49 ===
          supervisor: {local,sRPG_supervisor}
             started: [{pid,<0.71.0>},
                       {id,sRPG_server},
                       {mfargs,{sRPG_server,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,permanent},
                       {shutdown,2000},
                       {child_type,worker}]
true
```

Comment: Ah, that must've been it somehow. It's weird though, because I did comment out the changing of alarm_handlers and still got noproc error. I actually ended up reinstalling erlang and creating some new files from scratch and got it to work.